# Trying to show currently authenticated user post in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a Laravel project and I want to display currently authenticated users posts in view file, I am getting an error while trying to achieve that says

> "Class name must be a valid object or a string"...

my blade view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Swap 
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
                  
      @foreach($data as $dat)
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img
        src="{{asset('images/' . $dat->imogi)}}"
        alt="Trendy Pants and Shoes"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
      <div style="text-align: right;">
        <small style="color:#3490dc;">{{$dat->organazation}}</small> <small><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ $dat->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }}</small>
      </div>
      <h5 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dat->name}}</h5>
      <small><i class="fa fa-map-marker" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$dat->location}}</small> | <small><i class="fa fa-phone" style="color:#3490dc" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{$dat->contact}}</small>
      <hr/>
        <p class="card-text">
        <b>{{$dat->title}}</b>
        </p>
        <small style="color:#3490dc;">M{{$dat->price}}</small>
        <p class="card-text">
        {{$dat->message}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
            @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Work 
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="form-inline" type="get" action="{{url('/search_work')}}" role="search" method="get">
                    <input id="search-input" type="search" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."> 
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button> 
                    </form>

                    <br/>
      <p style="text-align:center">
      <button onclick="window.location.href='/workview'" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View</button><small style="color:#3490dc"> {{$count = DB::table('jobs')->count()}}</small> <small>Posts</small>
    </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sell 
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="form-inline" type="get" action="{{url('/search_sell')}}" role="search" method="get">
                    <input id="search-input" type="search" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>  
                    </form>

                    <br/>
      <p style="text-align:center">
      <button onclick="window.location.href='/sellview'" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View</button><small style="color:#3490dc"> {{$count = DB::table('announces')->count()}}</small> <small>Posts</small>
    </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tenders 
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
                    <form class="form-inline" type="get" action="{{url('/search_tender')}}" role="search" method="get">
                    <input id="search-input" type="search" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">  
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </form>

                    <br/>
      <p style="text-align:center">
      <button onclick="window.location.href='/tenderview'" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View</button><small style="color:#3490dc"> {{$count = DB::table('Kinds')->count()}} </small><small>Posts</small>
    </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

My controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use DB;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function mapost()
    {

       
        $data = Auth::user()->Announce::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

        return view('users.mapost',['data'=>$data]);
    }
}
```

My route in web.php

```
Route::get('users/mapost', 'PostController@mapost')->name('users.mapost');
```

I don`t know where I am getting this wrong, i will appreciate any help thanks in advance

Comment: Post User and Announce model files. The problem is mostly with this line `$data = Auth::user()->Announce::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
$data = Auth::user()->Announce::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Here you attempt to call the `orderBy` method of the `Auth::user()->Announce` class and of course, such class does not exist. It would make sense to do something like this:

```
Announce::where('user_id', $youruserid)->orderByDesc('created_at');
```